JSF Composite Components: Facet Content Not Rendering Through Nested Components
I'm facing an issue with rendering content passed through facets in nested composite components. Despite the facets being recognized as not empty, the content inside these facets does not appear on the final page. Below are the relevant parts of my implementation:

draft_scenario_details.xhtml

<ui:composition template="/virets/templates/base_template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:virets="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composite">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <virets:scenarioDetails>
            <f:facet name="additionalButtons">
                <p:outputLabel value="MY DRAFT"/>
            </f:facet>
        </virets:scenarioDetails>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>


scenarioDetails.xhtml

<ui:composition
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:virets="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composite">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:facet name="additionalButtons"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <virets:scenarioDetailsData>
            <f:facet name="additionalButtonsFacet">
                <cc:renderFacet name="additionalButtons"/>
            </f:facet>
        </virets:scenarioDetailsData>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:composition>


scenarioDetailsData.xhtml

<ui:composition
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:facet name="additionalButtonsFacet"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <cc:renderFacet name="additionalButtonsFacet"/>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:composition>

Issue:
The label "MY DRAFT" passed via the "additionalButtons" facet in viretsScenarioDetails should render in scenarioDetailsData, but it doesn't appear on the page.
What I have tried:

Ensuring facet names are consistent across components.
Directly rendering the facet in intermediate components to verify its presence.

Question:
How can I ensure that the content passed through facets in nested JSF composite components renders correctly in the final output?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Double rendering a facet is not what you want. The first "rendering" should just be a passing on of the facet.
scenarioDetails.xhtml:
<ui:composition
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:demo="urn:be:e-contract:ejsf:demo">
    <cc:interface componentType="scenarioDetails">
        <cc:facet name="additionalButtons"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <demo:scenarioDetailsData binding="#{cc.scenarioDetailsData}"/>
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:composition>

ScenarioDetails.java:
package be.e_contract.demo;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.NamingContainer;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase;
import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEventListener;
import javax.faces.event.ListenerFor;
import javax.faces.event.PostAddToViewEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@FacesComponent(ScenarioDetails.COMPONENT_TYPE)
@ListenerFor(systemEventClass = PostAddToViewEvent.class)
public class ScenarioDetails extends UIComponentBase implements NamingContainer, ComponentSystemEventListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScenarioDetails.class);

    public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "scenarioDetails";

    private UIComponent scenarioDetailsData;

    public void setScenarioDetailsData(UIComponent scenarioDetailsData) {
        this.scenarioDetailsData = scenarioDetailsData;
    }

    public UIComponent getScenarioDetailsData() {
        return this.scenarioDetailsData;
    }

    public ScenarioDetails() {
        setRendererType(null);
    }

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    @Override
    public void processEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        UIComponent facet = getFacet("additionalButtons");
        this.scenarioDetailsData.getFacets().put("additionalButtonsFacet", facet);
    }
}


Hi Frank,
I really appreciate the time and effort you took to help me with my JSF facets issue. Your solution provided the clarity I needed to understand the underlying mechanics and has significantly improved my implementation. Thanks to your guidance, I’m now able to render facet content correctly through nested composite components.
Thank you once again for your insightful and detailed help!

@AndySpu No problem. When starting to play with backing components, make sure to always keep them "stateless". For a deep dive into this subject, checkout section 2.9.1 Backing Component of: https://github.com/e-Contract/enterprise-jsf/releases/download/enterprise-jsf-1.15.0/enterprise-jsf.pdf
